# Customizing Contenteditable behavior with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, jquery-events

Currently under Firefox when I press return in a `contenteditable` paragraph it inserts a `br` tag creates a new paragraph tag and then puts a `br` tag inside that new paragraph. I would like to modify the behavior such that

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> = br tag (this is already the default)
- Enter duplicates the current element be it p, li, h1.. etc. and removes any trailing or leading (the W3C specification require some events that I could use, but I am not at all sure how implement them.
- Backspace at the beginning of an element will merge it with the preceding sibling if it exists
- Delete at the end of an element will merge it with the following sibling if it exists.

I have tried trapping keypress and checking for the return, delete, and backspace keys, but I can't seem to get the current caret position accurately or to prevent the default behavior if I am overriding it.

I would find it most helpful if anyone out there knows how to..

- Get and/or Set the current caret position in a contenteditable paragraph.
- prevent the default behavior of contenteditable
- attach the events required by the W3C recommendation. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Perhaps someone even knows of a user agent (browser) that already behaves in this way. That is acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To edit content-editable behavior, I'd do this:

```
$("#editable").bind("keypress",function(e){
   if(e.keyCode==13 && e.shiftKey){ //enter && shift
      e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default browser behavior
      this.html(this.html+"<br>");
   }
});
```

You can edit what's inside the `html` function. PS: I don't remember if jQuery has the `shiftKey` and `keyCode` on the event object...if anything goes wrong change `e` to `e.originalEvent`.

**To Get carret position**: 
In non-IE:

```
document.getSelection().anchorOffset
```

Comment: Thanks, This is basically what I tried but with one critical difference. I had e.preventDefault as the last call in the stack and you put it first. When put last it is ineffectual. Not sure why but it is. Thanks for your answer this gets me back in business. I still have some issues but will take another crack at 'em.

Comment: That's not going to work when the caret's not at the end of the editable text.

Comment: Yeah I know, you'd need to use something like this: `this.html(this.html().substring(anchorOffset)+"<br>"+this.html().substring(0,anchorOffset))`

Comment: @JCOC611: That would only work if the editable element contained a single text node, which would not be the case after inserting a `<br>` in the middle of it. For the general case, this isn't going to be viable.

Comment: It *is* completely possible, yet it would be pretty difficult, take tons of code...